# Firefox is not able to resolve relative path

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, firefox

On click of Sub Menus, Firefox is resolving the path as

```
> http://localhost:60236/Admin\NoDues\Test.aspx?mid=404
```

Whereas IE,Safari,Chorme resolving the same path as

```
> http://localhost:60236/Admin/NoDues/Test.aspx?mid=404
```

Please help how to resolve same in Firefox.

Comment: Any proxy added in firefox?

Comment: How to check proxy added in firefox?

Comment: code of menu generation would be appreciated

Comment: Options->AdvancedTab->Netowork(subtab)->Connection Setting->Proxy